# SQLite driver is not suitable

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to database with SQLite. There is no error appears in editor, but when I run the application I am getting error message that says;

"java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite//school.sqlite"

```
package dbUtil;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class dbConnection {

private static final String SQCONN  = "jdbc:sqlite//school.sqlite";

public static Connection getConnection()  throws SQLException {

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(SQCONN);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}

}
```

I did download the latest sqlite driver to library which is "sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1"

Can anybody help me for this error message? Thankyou,

Comment: I think the url should be: `jdbc:sqlite:/school.sqlite` (note the `:` after `sqlite`)  assuming the file `/school.sqlite` actually exists. Otherwise you need the full path: `jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/school.sqlite`

Comment: Thank you,  did miss it. I did fixed it now and getting another error, Access is denied. Let me check :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah, thank you so much. at least i knew how to fix acces denied problem by myself :) It works fine now, I did write the full path as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody sees this post and having the same problem, I just changed

```
private static final String SQCONN  = "jdbc:sqlite//school.sqlite";
```

to fullpath;

```
private static final String SQCONN  = "jdbc:sqlite:/C:/Users/MAMI/Desktop/OKUL/SchoolSystem/src/school.sqlite";
```

as @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned. Works fine now.

Thanks again